# Is null a non-declared variable?

Tags: java, null

If I declare a class attribute like this:

```
private static String month;
```

I don't know if later in the code is right to check like this:

```
if(month == null){
    month = "January";
}
```

My main question is, is null a non-declared variable?

What is the best approach to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`null` is a built-in special constant that represents an empty object reference, not a variable. When you declare a variable representing an object at the class or at the instance level, its initial value is set to `null`. When you declare a local variable, you must set its value explicitly - to `null` or to some object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is ok since all instance references are initialized to null.

But be careful, it is only true for instance references. The local ones must ALWAYS be initialized manually.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is always initialize your variable because if you dont then java will set it to null. Null means not referencing to any object which implies either not initialized or deliberately set as null

Answer (score 1):

a null variable is a reference which doesn't point to an instantiated object. SO you have a reference to a string which is yet to be pointed to a string.

Class member variables are initialised with nulls for object references. Inside a method they aren't, so you'll need to initialise it before you use it in order to make it compile in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

For objects null is the default value. In this case, month is String type, and String is object in Java so the default value for month is null